# How do you create a List using mailchimp API v1.3 php

Tags: php, api, list, mailchimp

i have been looking at the API http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/ and i can't find a way to create to a new list.

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible through the API.

It would probably open way too many doors for abusers.

Just make as many lists as you need from within the web-app. (and look at using groups to structure your list data instead)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to make a main list, and add interest and when sending filter by interest.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, the only way to add new lists is having a Partnerapi account in mailchimp.

https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/partnerapi/
https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/partnerapi/1.3/createlist.func.php