# Creating a List in mail chimp

Tags: mailchimp

How can we create a list in MailChimp using MailChimp API.I have gone through the belove link

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/#lists-methods

But couldn't find how to create a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It was not possible in the API 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985946/how-do-you-create-a-list-using-mailchimp-api-v1-3-php). I assume the same restriction applies to the new version 2.0 as well.

> It's not possible through the API.
>
> It would probably open way too many doors for abusers.
>
> Just make as many lists as you need from within the web-app. (and look at using groups to structure your list data instead)